# How is IntelliJ IDEA's Gradle language level determined?

Tags: intellij-idea, gradle

The JetGradle plugin that comes with IntelliJ shows my project as having a conflict. It says that my IDE language level is 1.7 and that my Gradle language level is 1.6.

The following code prints 1.7 for everything:

```
compileJava {
    println project.sourceCompatibility
    println project.targetCompatibility
    println sourceCompatibility
    println targetCompatibility
}
```

Running Gradle from the command line works fine. Running it inside of IDEA works as well. Both of these are using the 1.7 JDK. My IDEA project and module are also configured to use 1.7.

When I import the project via the Gradle build script, the version does default to 1.6. I have changed it to 1.7.

What is this "Gradle language level" and how can I modify it?

Thanks!

Comment: You can't do it with Gradle, however, when you "import project" in IDEA after running "./gradlew idea", there is a drop down selector for language. You can simply choose it there, prior to completing the import of the project

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Gradle does not expose the language level via the tooling api so I would think this is just the "default project" language as defined in intellij.

You can see details, and track back to the corresponding gradle issue, in this [jetbrains youtrack ticket](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-96615)

As to "how to fix it", I think the only real option is to not use use jetgradle & use the [gradle idea plugin](http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/idea_plugin.html). Intellij 12.1 will have a [much improved jetgradle plugin](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-53476) but if the info is not on the tooling api then it's difficult to see how this can be fixed.

EDIT: Gradle have just published an RC for 2.11 which (finally!) includes this feature, see [the release notes](https://docs.gradle.org/release-candidate/release-notes#enhanced-support-for-developing-java-projects-in-intellij-idea-and-eclipse) for details which explains that this support is there for both the tooling api (i.e. intellij jetgradle) and the gradle idea plugin.

Comment: That ticket is as good an answer as there is I suppose. Thanks.

Comment: We're at Gradle 15.0 and *still* not fixed

Comment: well it relies on https://issues.gradle.org/browse/GRADLE-2198 and gradle haven't fixed this, someone could send gradle a PR to add that to the tooling api though

Answer (score 4):

I'm a little late to the game here, but I use this to solve the issue:

```
apply plugin: 'idea'

allprojects {
  sourceCompatibility = 1.8
  targetCompatibility = 1.8
}

idea {
  project {
    jdkName = sourceCompatibility
    languageLevel = sourceCompatibility
    ipr {
      withXml {

        def xml = """<component name="GradleSettings">
    <option name="linkedExternalProjectsSettings">
      <GradleProjectSettings>
        <option name="distributionType" value="DEFAULT_WRAPPED" />
        <option name="externalProjectPath" value="\$PROJECT_DIR\$" />
        <option name="gradleJvm" value="$sourceCompatibility" />
        <option name="modules">
          <set>
            <option value="\$PROJECT_DIR\$" />
          </set>
        </option>
        <option name="myModules">
          <set>
            <option value="\$PROJECT_DIR\$" />
          </set>
        </option>
      </GradleProjectSettings>
    </option>
  </component>"""

        def node = it.asNode()
        node.append(new XmlParser().parseText(xml))
      }
    }
  }

  module {
    iml {
      withXml {
        def root = it.asNode()
        root.@'external.linked.project.id' = project.name
        root.@'external.linked.project.path' = '$MODULE_DIR$'
        root.@'external.root.project.path' = '$MODULE_DIR$'
        root.@'external.system.id' = "GRADLE"
        root.@'external.system.module.group' = project.group
        root.@'external.system.module.version' = project.version
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Then use `./gradlew idea` to generate the project metadata which sets the project language to 1.8. EDIT: The Gradle idea plugin deals only with file-based, rather than directory-based (.idea/) metadata. If you apply this to an existing project that uses directory-based metadata, you'll need to blow away the .idea/ folder in the project root

Note: setting jdkName to '1.8' assumes that there is a Java SDK registered in Intellij with the name '1.8'.

UPDATE 1:
The ipr file generated contains this block, indicating the use of Java 1.8 (note the 'languageLevel' and 'project-jdk-name' attributes)

```
<component name="ProjectRootManager" version="2" languageLevel="JDK_1_8" assert-keyword="true" jdk-15="true" project-jdk-type="JavaSDK" assert-jdk-15="true" project-jdk-name="1.8">
  <output url="file://$PROJECT_DIR$/out"/>
</component>
```

This should correspond directly with what you see in the Project Structure dialog:[image: Intellij and Gradle JDK Lang Level]

UPDATE 2: On project load, Intellij prompts you to "Import Gradle Project". For some reason this ignores the configured language level in the ipr file, and defaults to 1.6. The way to get around this is to pre-configure the ipr and applicable iml files so that it's aware of the Gradle integration. This way, you're not prompted to import the Gradle project and the language level stays at 1.8. The code block above has been updated to include the necessary config.

Comment: Wasn't working for me. I have added the plugin and the configuration to the gradle script, ran the gradle task, yet after importing the project back to IntelliJ source compatibility was still 1.6. I have checked the name of the SDK in IntelliJ and it was 1.8, so I suppose this should work. Any ideas maybe?

Comment: Hmm, have you reloaded the project in Intellij? In project structure, is both SDK and language level set to 1.8? Also, what version of Intellij are you using?

Comment: I have tried to generate and re-import the project into IntelliJ several times. Removed any previous project files too. Not sure why it is not working, maybe you could spot the error, here is my gradle script: https://gist.github.com/almosr/469c5ce876aa32f1c3f5#file-language-level-problem
Thanks for your help in advance!

Comment: Your build script works ok for me just running `gradle idea` (see update 1 in my answer above). What version of Intellij/Java/Gradle are you using? If the  contents of the ipr file don't match the Project Structure dialog then Intellij is changing it for some reason. FWIW, older versions of Intellij & Gradle didn't integrate well because the tooling API in Gradle was not very mature. My current setup is Intellij 15.0.2 / Java 1.8.0_66 / Gradle 2.9

Comment: Okay, I have found it: I was using Gradle 2.5. As soon as I upgraded to 2.9 it started to work. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Glad you got it working :) Not sure why 2.5 wouldn't work it's relatively new :/

Comment: Looks like I have spoken too early: it is not working after all. Tried again from scratch and language level is still not set. I will try to compare the workspace files when I have the time, maybe there is a clue.

Comment: FWIW, I tried it quickly using Gradle 2.5 (via wrapper) and it worked fine for my setup. Would be interested to hear about what the cause is if you get it figured out

Comment: These steps also don't work for me.  I set the in my `idea { project { languageLevel = '1.8' } }` and then `./gradlew idea`.  I even see the block XML block you showed in my IPR file but still my module is language level 6.

Comment: @MicahZoltu do you also perhaps have an .idea folder that is overriding the setting?

Comment: My problem was that after I ran `./gradlew idea` I would then open the project in IntelliJ and it would prompt me to integrate with Gradle.  Apparently, it was the act of saying yes to the popup that would break the Gradle integration.  I suspect that upgrading to Gradle 2.11 will resolve the issue since they have some IntelliJ integration improvements in it, but for the project in question I am unable to do that.

Comment: Good catch @MicahZoltu, I'll test this tomorrow and see if I can reproduce and/or find a workaround

Comment: @MicahZoltu I'm now seeing the same behaviour; after clicking "Import Gradle project" the language level is set to 1.6 even though the Gradle JVM is left at my 1.8 SDK in the import dialog :( I haven't yet found the reason for this or a workaround (apart from manually setting the language level in Project Settings).  I'll have a think about how this could be fixed. It respects the language level set by Gradle in the .ipr file as long as you don't import but that really negates the I in IDE.

Comment: I've figured out how make this work. You have to customize the IPR so that it's already aware of the Gradle integration, then it leaves the language level alone :)  See update 2 above and the modified sample code (you may need to scroll down to see it all). After adding the updated config, refresh the Intellij metadata with `./gradlew cleanIdea idea`

Answer (score 3):

It doesn't appear to be supported, but it's a simple one time fix.

- Navigate to:  File -> Project Structure Select "Modules" under
- Project Settings. (should already be) Change "Language level" to 7.0

Alternatively

- Drill down to and actual compile error in file.  Usually this is
  something like handling multiple errors in a catch block.
- Select the
  red helper icon that pops up, and "set language level to 1.7"

Answer (score 1):

I have a java/kotlin project. After messing around, I found that the order I apply the plugins in my gradle.build actually affected if the module itself or the main sourceset was given the correct language level:

```
plugins {
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.jvm' apply false
    id 'idea'
}
// have to apply in this order to fix idea.module.languageLevel
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.jvm'


sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8

idea {
    module {
        jdkName = '1.8'
        languageLevel = new IdeaLanguageLevel("1.8")
    }
}
```