# Gradle IDEA project language level issue

Tags: java, intellij-idea, gradle, libgdx

I'm trying to make gradle project in IDEA 13.1.3 and i cannot set project language level. I thought that it is basic functionality, but all I found is that
[question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14446638/how-is-intellij-ideas-gradle-language-level-determined)
Is there some way to avoid

I've tried to set project language level by adding this to my root build.gradle file:

```
idea {
project {
    jdkName  = 1.7
    languageLevel = 1.7
}}
```

After gradle sync language level in IDEA project settings sets to 6. My project is written in 7 lang version (diamonds, multicatch) and it won't compile.

Comment: Set project language level in what gradle or IntelliJ.  How did you try to do it?  What errors did you get?  What tells your the project level was or was not set?  What do you want to avoid?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For a long time, Gradle Idea plugin allows you to expose the project language level to Idea via the [idea/project](http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/dsl/org.gradle.plugins.ide.idea.model.IdeaProject.html) element:

```
apply plugin: 'idea'

idea {
    project {
        languageLevel = '1.7'
    }
}
```

At the moment configuring per-module language level in a multi-module gradle project is difficult but seems to be possible if you care to write and debug gradle logic that will modify the generated XML file similar to [this gradle forum topic](http://forums.gradle.org/gradle/topics/setting_per_module_language_level_in_intellij).

I think that [GRADLE-2198](http://issues.gradle.org/browse/GRADLE-2198) is the most relevant issue that will allow Idea (and other IDEs and tools) to easily determine the per-module language level. Please, vote for it.

Comment: thank you, i saw this bug and it is my case. just thought that people find some hook to avoid it...

Comment: You should actually use this instead: 

    idea {
        project {
            sourceCompatibility = "1.7"
        }
    }